# Search function in PowerPoint doesn't recognise End If-block and For-blocks

Tags: vba, search, powerpoint

I am trying to program code that basically works similarly to the Ctrl+F-search menu in Powerpoint. In this presentation, I have multiple profiles of different projects. Activating the macro should open a menu that allows you to input a search term which is scanned for on every slide in the presentation. The same term could be on multiple slides, for example if it is the name of the project leader.

I have written code which scans every slide and shape and then should select the text using the TextRange.find command. The problem is that after the first *Exit Do* command, the macro doesn't recognise any other *End If*, *Next* or *Exit Do* command. My code is as follows:

```
Sub Searchfunction()

    Dim TagObject As String
    Dim TexRng As TextRange
    Dim TexFrm As TextFrame
    Dim sld As Object
    Dim shp As Object
    Dim foundText As Object
    Dim Check As Boolean, Counter As Long
    Check = True
    
        TagObject= InputBox("What are you searching for?")
Do
    For Each sld In Application.ActivePresentation.Slides
        For Each shp In sld.Shapes
            If shp.HasTextFrame Then
                Set TexRng = shp.TextFrame.TextRange
                Set foundText = TexRng.Find(TagObject)
                    Do While Not (foundText Is Nothing)
                        With foundText.Select
                        End With
                        Check = MsgBox("Continue search?", vbYesNo)
                        If Check = False Then GoTo SearchEnd
                    Exit Do
            End If
        Next
    Next
Exit Do
MsgBox ("End of search, no further results.")

SearchEnd:

End Sub
```

Commenting out any End If still hands out the error message "End If without If-block" or "Next without for" despite there being an If, two Fors and a Do. How do I get VBA to recognise these blocks again?

Comment: A `Do`-Loop need be ended with the `Loop`-Keyword, not with `Exit Do`. Exit is used, if you want to escape the loop without checking the condition again. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Reference/User-Interface-Help/doloop-statement. Your outermost `Do` seems unnecessary to me.

Comment: @FunThomas Thank you for the heads up. I deleted the outer Do and replaced the inner do by using "While ... Wend" and it works like a treat. I also changed some other lines so that it actually selects the slide the search object is on. Your advice was very helpful however, thank you very much! :)
I'll update the question to provide the code I used in the end as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code now works as intended and selects the slide which the search object is on. My final code looks as follows:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Searchfunction()

    Dim TagObject As String
    Dim TexRng As TextRange
    Dim TexFrm As TextFrame
    Dim sld As Object
    Dim shp As Object
    Dim foundText As Object
    Dim Check As Boolean
    Dim Counter As Long
    Counter = 1
    Check = True
    
        TagObject= InputBox("What are you searching for?")
        
    For Each sld In Application.ActivePresentation.Slides
        For Each shp In sld.Shapes
            If shp.HasTextFrame Then
                Set TexRng = shp.TextFrame.TextRange
                Set foundText = TexRng.Find(TagObject)
                    While Not (foundText Is Nothing)
                        ActivePresentation.Slides(Counter).Select
                        Check = MsgBox("Continue Search?", vbYesNo)
                        If Check = False Then GoTo SearchEnd
                        Set foundText = Nothing
                    Wend
            End If
        Next
        Counter = Counter + 1
    Next
    
MsgBox ("End of search, no further results.")

SearchEnd:

End Sub
```

If you want to search something while doing a presentation you need to replace the line `ActivePresentation.Slides(Counter).Select` with `ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.GotoSlide(Counter)`.